# How can I insert a <script type='text/javascript' src=''> tag on a 3rd party webpage using rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The question alone could be a little confusing so here's a brief explanation:

I want to give 3rd parties a javascript call example: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myrailswebsite.com/controller/action?params'>`  using which they can call a action with a few params on my rails server.  My action after evaluating the params should insert another `<script type='text/javascrtipt' src='http://my_partner_site.com/xxx.php?evaluated_params'>` tag into the 3rd party's webpage which should get evaluated while the page completes loading.

I have tried using

```
    def action
      #<evaluate params...snipped for clarity>
      render :update |page|
        page << "<script type='text/javascript' src=...>"
      end
    end
```

But I get an error in firebug saying "missing } in XML expression" which is due to the try catch block which rails puts around the script tag and parser thinking that this is an xml expression.  I can't rely on 3rd party websites I am integrating with to have prototype.js included.

I have tried other options like rjs and respond_to format.js as well but no luck.  Please help.

Comment: I don't understand anything of rails. But it seems to me, that you send HTML content back to the user. That's wrong, because you output HTML code in a `<script>` tag. Therefore you should use correct DOM manipulation statements to insert another script tag. See http://molily.de/weblog/javascript-asynchron (sorry only in german)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
def action
  #<evaluate params...snipped for clarity>
  render :update |page|
    page << "document.write(\"<script type='text/javascript' src=...>\");"
  end
end
```

Comment: This this help you along your way?